# What does this fstab configuration line mean?

Tags: raid, fstab

I am trying to mount a RAID array on my computer, and I found a guide on the Internet that told me to add this file to `/etc/fstab`:

```
 /dev/md0 /mnt/raid/ext4 defaults 0 0
```

What does `/dev/md0` and `0 0` mean in this line?  Or, can you break down and explain the line a little better, explaining what each part of the line is?

Comment: Did it say to put this in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: yes it did @ThomasW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This *looks* like an `/etc/fstab` entry, but it's missing a filesystem type.

Let's split your line into its relevant parts, and analyze individually.

More info on `fstab` lines can be found in the [manpage for `fstab`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/fstab.5.html). (this link is for Xenial's manpage on `fstab`)

> Note: I believe this line is typoed, and that you really meant to use this line:
>
> `/dev/md0 /mnt/raid/ ext4 defaults 0 0`

---

**First Field:** `/dev/md0`

This indicates the block device to mount.  In this case, `/dev/md0`, which is a special file indicating the device/partition to the system.

---

**Second field:** `/mnt/raid/ext4`

This indicates where on the Linux system this device file is to be mounted.  In this case, in the folder path it specifies.

Given the next section, and my quote-box above indicating that I think you've typoed, I believe this should be `/mnt/raid`.

---

***Missing Third Field: Filesystem Type***

When using `fstab` for mounting things, we *always* have some type of filesystem declared in the third item.  In your `fstab` string, this is being skipped, which can cause this to not function right.

Going solely by what appears to be a typo in the mount path, and my quote-box above indicating that I believe you typoed, it seems this should be `ext4`, but I do not know whether this is the case for you.  Determine the filesystem in use on your RAID array, and specify it, adding right before 'defaults' what filesystem to use.

---

**Fourth Field:** `defaults` - Mount Options to use.

Borrowed from my Other Answer on a different question, `defaults` indicates a default set of mount options:

> `defaults` - passes default mount options (`rw` - read/write, `suid` - allow set-user-identifier or set-group-identifier bits to take effect, `dev` - interpret character or block special devices on the filesystem, `exec` - permit execution of binaries, `auto` - allows mounting with the `-a` option of `mount`, `nouser` - prohibits a user from mounting, `async` - permit asynchronous I/O with the filesystem.)

---

**Fifth field:** `0`

This field is used by `dump` to determine which filesystems need to be dumped; `0` indicates this is not needed on this filesystem.

---

**Sixth field:** `0`

This field is used by `fsck` to determine the order in which filesystem checks are done at boot time.  A `0` here indicates that the filesystem should not be checked by `fsck` when an at-boot filesystem check is done.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you added this line to `/etc/fstab` - You can not just add a line there and hope something useful will happen. If it is `/etc/fstab` you normally find the meaning at the beginning of this very file:

`# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>`

for more info see manual

`man fstab`

or use google

You have a typo in your file: replace `[..] /mnt/raid/ext4 [..]` with `[..] /mnt/raid ext4 [..]` ( / with whitespace )

`<file system>` device which contains file system

first 0 (fifth field): is used by `dump` program (`man dump`)

second 0 (sixth field) is used by `fsck` at boot time

Comment: I'm downvoting this because the answer basically explains "see the fstab manual for more details".  You are also slightly inaccurate when you refer to `<file system>` in your format example - this is more commonly referred to as the 'block device' to mount, rather than the filesystem.

Comment: @ThomasW. ok - but that is how it is referred to in standard `/etc/fstab` in ubuntu and debian and maybe other OS - just copied & pasted - as you did with `man fstab` ;)

Comment: Actually, I didn't copy paste from the manpage ;)  Everything I wrote was paraphrased :)